# Install omxplayer on the commandline

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer

OMXPlayer is a standalone commandline OMX player for the Raspberry PI.

I cannot find it in the repository. How do I install it?

Comment: Repository : https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer

Comment: which OS you are running?

Answer (score 2):

You can install it easily as superuser:

```
sudo su
```

First you need install required dependencies:

```
apt-get install libpcre3 fonts-freefont-ttf
```

Optionally you can install `fbset`, I highly recommend it if you are going to use --refresh/-r option:

```
apt-get install fbset
```

When you have installed the dependencies you can go ahead downloading the omxplayer and install it with dpkg:

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://omxplayer.sconde.net/builds/omxplayer_0.3.6~git20150505~b1ad23e_armhf.deb
dpkg -i omxplayer_*_armhf.deb
```

Note:
the latest version will change, so this is just the example for the (currently latest) version from 20150505.